# Find the most frequent number in an array, with limited memory

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sorting

How to find the most frequent number in an array? The array can be extremely large, for example 2GB and we only have limited memory, say 100MB.

*I'm thinking about external sort, which is sorting and than duplicating numbers that are next to each other. Or hashma. But don't know what to do with the limited memory. And I'm even not sure if external sort is a good idea for this.*

Comment: You can think of in place sorting and then iterating over the array. However it shall destroy your original array.

Comment: @JudyJiang Is there a range in which the numbers lie?

Comment: Also take a look at my answer  here (http://stackoverflow.com/a/23441932/191148)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assumptions:

- Integer is 4 bytes.
- There are less then (100 MB / 4 B) = (104857600 / 4) = 26214400 distinct integers in the 2 GB array. Every number maps into 0-26214399 index range.

Let's do the histogram.

1. Make buckets in our 100 MB space. It's an integer array called `histogram`, which can store up to 26214400 counters. Counters are initally set to 0.
2. Iterate once through the 2 GB array. When you read `x`, do `histogram[x]++`.
3. Find the maximum in the `histogram`, iterating through it once. If the maximum is `histogram[i]`, then `i` is the most frequent number.

The bottleneck is step 2, iterating through 2 GB array, but we do it only once.

If the second assumptions doesn't hold (i.e. there are more than 26214400 distinct integers):

Make histogram for numbers with indices from 0 to 26214399. Keep the most frequent number from histogram. Make histogram for numbers with indices from 26214400 to 52428798. Keep the most frequent number from the histogram and the previous most frequent number. And so on.

In the worst case, with 2^32 distinct numbers, it will do (2^32 / 26214400 + 1) = 164 iterations over that 2 GB array.

In general, it will do (NUMBER_OF_DISTINCT_NUMBERS / 26214400 + 1) iterations.

Comment: @Downvoter Could you please comment (so maybe I can improve my answer)?

Comment: Your first suggestions assumes that one knows exactly which numbers are present - otherwise it might not be possible to give a bijection of the occuring numbers to the range 0-26214399, even if there are only so few distinct numbers. Your second suggestion is very inefficient (consider eg. the case that the op actually has 64 bit numbers...)

Answer (score 2):

In the worst case, all your numbers are distinct except for one number which appears twice, and there's no way to detect this in main memory unless you have the two duplicate numbers loaded into main memory at the same time, which is unlikely without sorting if your total data size is much larger than main memory size. In that case, aysmptotically the best thing to do is sort numbers in batches and save to disk in files, and then do a merge sort merge step reading in all the sorted files into memory a few lines at a time, and outputting the merged sorted list to a new file. Then you go through the aggregate sorted file in order and count how many times you see each number, keeping track of which number has occurred the most times.

If you assume that the most frequent number is 50% frequency or higher, then you can do much better. You can solve the problem with constant extra memory just going through the list of numbers once. Basically you start by initializing the most common value (MCV) to the first number and initialize a counter N to 1. Then you go through the list. If the next number in the list is the MCV, you increase N by one. Otherwise you decrease N by 1. If N is 0 and the next number is different than MCV, then you set MCV to the new number and set N to 1. It is easy to prove this will terminate with the most common value stored in MCV.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what the hypotheses are, an even better way of doing it might be using the MJRTY algorithm:

http://www.cs.utexas.edu/~moore/best-ideas/mjrty/

Or its generalization:

http://www.cs.yale.edu/homes/el327/datamining2011aFiles/ASimpleAlgorithmForFindingFrequentElementsInStreamsAndBags.pdf

The idea is that with exactly two variables (a counter and a value store) you can determine, if there exists a majority element (appearing strictly more than 50% of the time), what that element is. The generalization require (k+1) counters and value stores to find the elements appearing 100/k%.

Because these are only candidates to majority (if there is are k-majority elements, those are they; but if there are no k-majority elements, than these are just random elements there by chance), a second pass on the data could help you get the exact count of the candidates, and determine which one, if any, is a majority element.

This is extremely fast and memory efficient.

There are few other optimizations, but with 4kb of memory, you should be able to find the majority element of 2GB of data with good probability - depending on the type of data you have.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming 4-byte integers, you can fit (100 / 4) = 25MB integers into available memory.

1. Read through your big file, counting each occurrence of and number in the range 0 ... 25MB-1.  Use a big array to accumulate counts.
2. Find the number which occurs most frequently, store the number and its frequency and clear the array.
3. Read through the big file repeating the counting process for numbers in the range 25MB ... 50MB-1.
4. Find the number which occurs most frequently in the new array.  Compare it with the number/frequency you stored at step 2.  Store the number/frequency of the one with the higher frequency and clear the array.
5. Lather, rinse, repeat.

ETA: If we can assume that there is one single answer, that there aren't two different numbers with the same highest frequency, then you can discard all numbers if the array for a particular range shows a tie.  Otherwise the problem of storing the winner for each range becomes more complex.

Answer (score -1):

If you have limited memory but a reasonable amount of processing power and super fast speed isn't an issue, depending on your dataset you could try something like:

Iterate through array counting number of numbers 1 to 1000. Keep the one with the biggest count. Then count 1001 to 2000. Keep the biggest count between these, and the biggest one from the first batch. Repeat until all numbers have been counted.

I'm sure there are many optimisations for this based on the specifics of your dataset.

Comment: That's not going to work. It's quite possible for the single number that has the highest count to be in a range that doesn't have the highest count. For example if your numbers are in the range 0-100 and you split them into buckets of 10. Say the number 21 occurs 3 times and it's the only number in the range 0-20. But every number from 10 to 19 occurs once. You'll pick the 10's bucket and throw away the 20's bucket.

Comment: I think you misunderstand. You count every number from 1 to 10. Say 5 appears 3 times, so you keep 5=3. Then you count every number from 11 to 20, and 17 appears 2 times. You keep the highest out of the running highest (5=3) and the latest highest (17=2) so you keep 5=3. Does that make sense?

Comment: I did misunderstand your approach. What you describe would work. I tried to undo my downvote, but it's saying that the answer must be edited first.