# Fastest way for Grouping and Selecting list of integers (top occurrences)

Tags: c#, performance, list

I have a large list of integers having from 1 million to even 100 million integers.

I want to rank them by their occurrences and select top `K` (here `K=10`) results.

I already tried 4 different ways by which my `Method1` is the fastest. Parallelization didn't beat my own grouping code in `Method1` and also it resulted in inaccurate ranking due to thread race conditions.

`Method1` and `Method4` results are accurate and correct while `Method2` and `Method3` may have inaccurate ranking due to race conditions.

Now, I'm looking for any possible code faster than `Method1` or a fix for parallelized methods making them accurate and then faster than `Method1`.

```
class Benchmark
{
    static List<int> input = new List<int>();
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int count = int.Parse(args[0]);

        Random rnd = new Random();

        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
            input.Add(rnd.Next(1, count));

        DoBench();

        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    private static void DoBench()
    {
        for (int i = 1; i <= 4; i++)
        {
            DateTime start = DateTime.Now;

            List<KeyValuePair<int, int>> results = null;

            switch (i)
            {
                case 1:
                    results = Method1();
                    break;
                case 2:
                    results = Method2();
                    break;
                case 3:
                    results = Method3();
                    break;
                case 4:
                    results = Method4();
                    break;
            }

            int resultsCount = 10;

            var topResults = results.Take(resultsCount).OrderByDescending(x => x.Value).ThenBy(x => x.Key).ToArray();

            for (int j = 0; j < resultsCount; j++)
                Console.WriteLine("No {0,2}: {1,8}, Score {2,4}", j + 1, topResults[j].Key, topResults[j].Value);

            Console.WriteLine("Time of Method{0}: {1} ms", i, (long)DateTime.Now.Subtract(start).TotalMilliseconds);
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }

    private static List<KeyValuePair<int, int>> Method1()
    {
        Dictionary<int, int> dic = new Dictionary<int, int>();

        for (int i = 0; i < input.Count; i++)
        {
            int number = input[i];

            if (dic.ContainsKey(number))
                dic[number]++;
            else
                dic.Add(number, 1);
        }

        var sorted_results = dic.OrderByDescending(x => x.Value).ToList();

        return sorted_results;
    }

    private static List<KeyValuePair<int, int>> Method2()
    {
        var sorted_results = input.AsParallel().GroupBy(x => x)
               .Select(g => new KeyValuePair<int, int>(g.Key, g.Count()))
               .OrderByDescending(x => x.Value).ToList();

        return sorted_results;
    }

    private static List<KeyValuePair<int, int>> Method3()
    {
        ConcurrentDictionary<int, int> dic = new ConcurrentDictionary<int, int>();

        input.AsParallel<int>().ForAll((number) =>
        {
            dic.AddOrUpdate(number, 1, new Func<int, int, int>((key, oldValue) => oldValue + 1));
        });

        var sorted_results = dic.OrderByDescending(x => x.Value).ToList();

        return sorted_results;
    }

    private static List<KeyValuePair<int, int>> Method4()
    {
        var sorted_results = input.GroupBy(x => x)
               .Select(g => new KeyValuePair<int, int>(g.Key, g.Count()))
               .OrderByDescending(x => x.Value).ToList();

        return sorted_results;
    }
}
```

Comment: So? Is your `Method1` slow for you? Are you looking for fixes for 2/3? Do you have goal how you want to improve your histogram+sort method? (I don't think you can get anything as compact and readable as you have in 1 now, there is no heap in the .Net which could help with sort, and splitting source into ranges to fix parallel version will take several more lines and may not speed things up)

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov, sorry I forgot to say my goal. Yes my Method1 is slow for my scenario since it's going to be executed several thousand times. And any possible fix making parallelized versions faster

Comment: I'd try map-reduce... split your array into continuous ranges by number of CPUs (i.e. 1-999,1000-1999) compute separate histograms (no locking) and than merge resulting histograms in single thread. Than sort (or find [heap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_%28data_structure%29) implementation to get Top(N) results)... Note that it makes sense only if your dataset is relatively small (as in your case) and there is no additional cost to access the data (like it is in memory already, no disk/network IO).

Comment: Is there a positive difference if you use method 2 without the AsParallel() ?
It looks for me that the AsParallel is just causing overhead.

Comment: @CSharpie, you are correct. I was looking for an accurate parallelized version which didn't work in practice yet ...

Answer (score 2):

I found a faster dictionary implementation for grouping section. I used the [FastDictionary](https://code.google.com/p/mapreduce-net/source/browse/MapReduce.NET/Collections/FastDictionary.cs) class from the [MapReduce.NET](https://code.google.com/p/mapreduce-net/) project written by Adam Horvath ([link](http://blog.teamleadnet.com/2012/07/ultra-fast-hashtable-dictionary-with.html)).

Using `FastDictionary` I updated my `Method1` and wrote a new `Method6` which is faster. Then I add the fast sort from @Mattew Watson and wrote `Method7`. Finally I benched them altogether.

**Edit**

I just come up with a brilliant idea to speedup grouping section even more in `Method8`. The idea is to use a predefined array with the size of maximum of input array so I could replace dictionary with an array. Of course the `Method8` is efficient when the the ratio of `Maximum-Element-of-Input/Size-Of-Input` approaches to `1` and `Maximum-Element-of-Input` number of integers fits in memory.

**Edit 2**

I wrote another 3 methods named `Method9`, `Method10` and `Method11`.

I noticed that gathering grouping result and adding them to list in `Method8` requires large amount of unnecessary memory so I modified `partialSort` a little and removed the memory overhead.

Again, I noticed that I'm holding relatively small amounts in 4 bytes of `Int32`. Why?! So assuming that no element in input list occurs more than `65535` (`short.MaxValue`) I simply replaced the `Int32` array with a `short` array occupying half the memory.

Once again, I noticed if we have a memory critical scenario and again assuming that most of elements in input array occur less than `255` (`byte.MaxValue`) we can use a `byte` alongside an ordinary dictionary for elements with high occurrences. This technique is a little slow due to several checks during grouping operation and also requires merging of results at the end, but as you can see in chart, its memory usage is much much less than others even less than my initial methods based on dictionaries.

**Timings:**

[image: Timing of different methods]

**Memory Usage:**

[image: Memory usage of different methods]

**Timing Comparison**
[image: Timing]

**Memory Comparison**
[image]

**Method 6:**

```
    private static List<KeyValuePair<int, int>> Method6()
    {            
        FastDictionary<int, int> dic = new FastDictionary<int, int>();

        for (int i = 0; i < input.Count; i++)
        {
            int number = input[i];

            int pos = dic.InitOrGetPosition(number);
            int curr = dic.GetAtPosition(pos);
            dic.StoreAtPosition(pos, ++curr);
        }

        var sorted_results = dic.OrderByDescending(x => x.Value).ToList();

        return sorted_results;
    }
```

**Method 7:**

```
    private static List<KeyValuePair<int, int>> Method7()
    {            
        FastDictionary<int, int> dic = new FastDictionary<int, int>();

        for (int i = 0; i < input.Count; i++)
        {
            int number = input[i];

            int pos = dic.InitOrGetPosition(number);
            int curr = dic.GetAtPosition(pos);
            dic.StoreAtPosition(pos, ++curr);
        }

        var result = dic.ToList();
        partialSort(result, 10);

        return result;
    }
```

**Method 8**

```
    private static List<KeyValuePair<int, int>> Method8()
    {
        int[] dic = new int[input.Max() + 1];

        for (int i = 0; i < input.Count; i++)
        {
            dic[input[i]]++;
        }

        List<KeyValuePair<int, int>> list = new List<KeyValuePair<int, int>>();
        for (int i = 0; i < dic.Length; i++)
        {
            if (dic[i] > 0)
                list.Add(new KeyValuePair<int, int>(i, dic[i]));
        }            

        partialSort(list, 10);

        return list;
    }
```

**Method 9**

```
    private static List<KeyValuePair<int, int>> Method9()
    {
        int[] dic = new int[input.Max() + 1];

        for (int i = 0; i < input.Count; i++)
        {
            dic[input[i]]++;
        }

        List<KeyValuePair<int, int>> list = partialSort(dic, 10);

        return list;
    }
```

**Method 10**

```
    private static List<KeyValuePair<int, int>> Method10()
    {
        short[] dic = new short[input.Max() + 1];

        for (int i = 0; i < input.Count; i++)
        {
            dic[input[i]]++;
        }

        List<KeyValuePair<int, int>> list = partialSort(dic, 10);

        return list;
    }
```

**Method 11**

```
    private static List<KeyValuePair<int, int>> Method11()
    {
        byte[] dic = new byte[input.Max() + 1];

        Dictionary<int, int> largeDic = new Dictionary<int, int>();

        int index = 0;
        int val = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < input.Count; i++)
        {
            index = input[i];
            val = dic[index];

            if (val < 255)
                dic[index] = (byte)(val + 1); // casting to byte
            else
            {
                if (largeDic.ContainsKey(index))
                {
                    largeDic[index]++;
                }
                else
                {
                    largeDic.Add(index, 255 + 1);
                }
            }
        }

        List<KeyValuePair<int, int>> list = new List<KeyValuePair<int, int>>();

        if (largeDic.Count == 0)
        {
            list = partialSort(dic, 10);
        }
        else
        {
            if (largeDic.Count < 10)
            {
                list.AddRange(largeDic.OrderByDescending(x => x.Value));

                var tempList = partialSort(dic, 50);

                list.AddRange(tempList.Except(list, new KeyValueComparer()).Take(10 - list.Count));
            }
            else
            {
                list = largeDic.OrderByDescending(x => x.Value).Take(10).ToList();
            }
        }

        return list;
    }
```

**Partial Sorting**

Different overloads only have different parameter types(`int[]`, `short[]`, `byte[]`)

```
    private static List<KeyValuePair<int, int>> partialSort(int[] list, int k)
    {
        int[] topIndexes = new int[k];

        for (int i = 0; i < k; ++i)
        {
            int maxIndex = i;
            int maxValue = list[i];

            for (int j = i + 1; j < list.Length; ++j)
            {
                if (list[j] > maxValue)
                {
                    maxIndex = j;
                    maxValue = list[j];
                }
            }

            var temp = list[i];
            list[i] = list[maxIndex];
            list[maxIndex] = temp;

            topIndexes[i] = maxIndex;
        }

        List<KeyValuePair<int, int>> top = new List<KeyValuePair<int, int>>();

        for (int i = 0; i < k; i++)
            top.Add(new KeyValuePair<int, int>(topIndexes[i], list[i]));

        return top;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can significantly speed up the part of the algorithm which finds the 10 highest counts, bu using a selection sort.

The quickest way to do that is by using a [QuickSelect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quickselect) algorithm, but that's a little too complex for me to write here.

Instead, I'll demonstrate using a [Partial Selection Sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quick_select).

Here's a `Method5()` which uses it. It's basically the same as `Method1()`, except it uses the partial sort instead of a full sort at the last stage:

```
private static List<KeyValuePair<int, int>> Method5()
{
    Dictionary<int, int> dic = new Dictionary<int, int>();

    for (int i = 0; i < input.Count; i++)
    {
        int number = input[i];

        if (dic.ContainsKey(number))
            dic[number]++;
        else
            dic.Add(number, 1);
    }

    var result = dic.ToList();
    partialSort(result, 10);

    return result;
}

private static void partialSort(List<KeyValuePair<int, int>> list, int k)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < k; ++i)
    {
        int maxIndex = i;
        int maxValue = list[i].Value;

        for (int j = i+1; j < list.Count; ++j)
        {
            if (list[j].Value > maxValue)
            {
                maxIndex = j;
                maxValue = list[j].Value;
            }
        }

        var temp = list[i];
        list[i] = list[maxIndex];
        list[maxIndex] = temp;
    }
}
```

I timed a RELEASE (not debug) build, and this seems nearly three times faster on my PC when `K == 10`.

It will be proportionally faster the smaller K is relative to the size of the collection. For larger values of `K` (particularly where `K` approaches the size of the collection) then this algorithm is likely to be slower than the plain sort.

*DO NOT* use this algorithm if `K` is expected to be large. Its efficiency is highly dependent on the value of `K` being small relative to the size of the collection.

Comment: Thanks @MatthewWatson.It speeds up the sorting as it holds less elements than all, but in my tests the grouping code accounts for two third of total operation time which reduces the sort improvement effect.